# Material-UI GridTile touch events

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the library [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui) and i have a `GridList` with `GridTile`s that can respond to two different touch events: a touch on the tile should let the user navigate to another route and a touch on the 'actionIcon' should star it. I defined onTouchTap on both the GridTile and the IconButton that is passed to the tile itself as an action icon, something like that:

```
    <GridTile
      onTouchTap={(e) => {
        onTileTouch(id)
      }}
      key={id}
      title={'...'}
      subtitle={'...'}
      actionIcon={<IconButton onTouchTap={
        addToFavourites(id)
      }/>}>
        <img src={'...'} />
    </GridTile>
```

but what i get is that every touchTap events are consumed by the GridTile. How can i achieve what i need?

Answer (score 4):

I think this'll work - you could include an onClick event in the GridList that the GridTile is under instead of the onTouchTap, then handle the onTouchTap event in the IconButton. It should call them separately

```
<GridList onClick={ (e) => {
    onTileTouch(id)
  }}
    <GridTile
      key={id}
      title={'...'}
      subtitle={'...'}
      actionIcon={<IconButton onTouchTap={
        addToFavourites(id)
      }/>}>
        <img src={'...'} />
    </GridTile>
</GridList
```